# <ui:param> facelet tag performance

Tags: performance, jsf, richfaces, seam, facelets

I have a file with large content to display. For example in displaying user profile, every EL expression in `<h:outputText/>` needs an userId as an argument to bean which is taken from the session context. I declared this userId in xhtml file as

```
<ui:param name="userId" value="#{currentUser.id}"/>
```

I am passing this userId to bean methods as

```
<h:outputText value="#{profile.getAddress(userId)}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{profile.getContact(userId)}"/>

<s:link>
<f:param name="userId" value="#{userId}"/>
</s:link>
```

I am expectiong the session variable is invoked once for a page. But each time when the userId is processed the sessiion variable is called. Is this the correct behaviour? How to optimize this?

Comment: I have the same problem. `<c:set` is supposed to cache the variable but it doesn't work with Facelets well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the correct behavior. It would be interesting to see which is faster. I would guess it is faster to inject the currentUser in your profile component, and then to retrieve the correct object from there, instead of getting the address and contact by the userId each time. (Depends if you cache it in the component or not).

However, I would try to optimize it by injecting the currentUser in the profile component. That is the standard way of doing it.